# Regular expression that contains 15 digits alphanumeric with comma separator

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I want an regular expression that contains 15 character with alpha numeric and also with comma separate. For example, I have make one regular expression

```
^((\\d{15})[,])*(\\d{15})$
```

it's fine for numeric values only that have 15 characters and is comma separated.

```
Example string 123456789012345,987654321054321
```

I want it also check for alphabet(alphanumeric) like

```
22AAAAA0000A1Z5,22BBBBB0000B1Z5,LMNOP1234AS19P1
```

Comment: Just change \d{15} to [0-9A-Z]  ^(([0-9A-Z]{15})[,])*([0-9A-Z]{15})$

Comment: @Mystery thanks for editing.

Comment: No problem, welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply Do with `w`=> `^((\w{15})[,])*(\w{15})$`

1.`\w{15}` matches any word character `(equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])`

[`Demo regex`](https://regex101.com/r/t2DHe4/1/)

Working snippet

```js
var a ="22AAAAA0000A1Z5,22BBBBB0000B1Z5,LMNOP1234AS19P1"
console.log(/^((\w{15})[,])*(\w{15})$/g.exec(a))
```

Comment: `\w` includes the underscore character **_**, if it is undesired `\b` could be used instead.

Comment: @Prasad thanks for reply and also it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want output as separate group.

```js
var string = "22AAAAA0000A1Z5,22BBBBB0000B1Z5,LMNOP1234AS19P1,"

var result = string.match(/([a-z0-9A-Z]{15}[,])/g)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: thanks for reply but i have applied regular expression given by another responder(prasad) and also it fine to me.